# Flow - Count checkbox true and attached files

Tags: visual-workflow, formula, files, upload, count

Ive created a flow that only allow users to attached files according to the number of checkbox.
If i got 3 checkbox true, i would like found 3 files on the record.

For this, ive created a formula field that will count the number of checkbox true and ive create a DLRS who count the number of ContentDocumentLink associated.. + VR to ensure the two fields are not <> !

However, my formula field is triggered only when the record is save. How can i calculate in my flow the number of checkbox true, beforce saving? My decision component is not working cause formula field is referenced.. :(

[image: My decision not working cause formula field is referenced]

Thanks guys!
Regards

Answer (score 0):

As you've discovered, a formula field is calculated only after the record is saved.  Instead, you must build the formula within your Flow.  If the only purpose of the formula field is for your Flow condition, you can eliminate the formula field.